# Netbeans / Eclipse for Spring 3.1

Tags: netbeans

Can any one tell **which IDE is better if i want to come up with an application which uses Springs 3.1 Framework**.

Answer (score 0):

I'll vote for eclipse, due the possible integration of Spring Tool Suite, but will depend on your past experience. Try both and decide yourself.